# Carbon - A textual month could not be found Trailing data

Tags: laravel-4, php-carbon

I'm using Laravel. I get the following error when trying to display a date:

```
A textual month could not be found Trailing data
```

Format is `j M Y`, date is `2014-12-13 10:00:00`

I don't get where is the error.

Any toughts?

Comment: It'll probably the data you feed into the Carbon that's causing the issue. Check what's the value that you're passing to Carbon

Comment: This is the type of data I'm getting from the database: ```2014-12-13 10:00:00```

Comment: Can you also post the code where you display the date?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: Using createFromFormat with the second parameter not being a Carbon object was giving me this same error. Using `Carbon::parse::` instead of `createFromFormat` seemed to fix the issue:

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date) {
    $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
}
```